# Arduino wireless nrf24l01 i2c running slow

Tags: c++, performance, arduino, i2c

I made a platform for a wireless anamatronics using arduino pro mini's and doing wireless communication with nrf24l01 modules. I am also using Neopixels for lights. The issue is that something is the program is slowing down the cycles and makes the fading led animations really jerky. Can anyone help me find what is holding things up with my code or is it just the arduino I am using that is not up to snuff.

I am including the code from the arduino pro mini controlling the puppet.

````
#define PIN            3
#define NUMPIXELS     6
#define UP 0
#define DOWN 1
Adafruit_NeoPixel strip = Adafruit_NeoPixel(NUMPIXELS, PIN, NEO_GRB + NEO_KHZ800);
#include <SPI.h>
#include <nRF24L01.h>
#include <RF24.h>
RF24 radio(9, 10); // CE, CSN
//const byte address[6] = "00001";
const byte addresses[][6] = {"00001", "00002"};

int colorMode = 0;
unsigned long previousFadeMillis;
int brightness;
int fadeInterval = 1;
const byte pwmLED = 5;
byte fadeDirection = UP;
int fadeValue = 0;
byte fadeIncrement = 5;

// define directions for LED fade
#define UP 0
#define DOWN 1

// constants for min and max PWM
const int minPWM = 100;
const int maxPWM = 255;

typedef struct A_t {
  int X;
  int Y;
  int R;
  int G;
  int B;
  int Br;
};
A_t SendData;

typedef struct B_t {
  float nedVoltage;
  int connectCount;
};
B_t NedData;
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);
  radio.begin();
  //radio.openReadingPipe(0, address);
  //radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);

  radio.openWritingPipe(addresses[0]); // 00001
  radio.openReadingPipe(1, addresses[1]); // 00002
  radio.setPALevel(RF24_PA_MIN);
  radio.stopListening();
  NedData.connectCount = 0;

  strip.begin();
  strip.setPixelColor(4, 0, 200, 0);
  strip.setPixelColor(5, 0, 200, 0);
}
void loop() {
  unsigned long currentMillis = millis();
  switch (colorMode) {
    case 0:
      doTheFade(currentMillis);
      break;
    case 1:
      doTheFade(currentMillis);
      break;
    case 2:
      doTheFade(currentMillis);
      break;
    case 3:
      doTheFade(currentMillis);
      break;
  }
  while (radio.available()) {
    radio.read( &SendData, sizeof(SendData) );
    //char text[32] = "";
    //radio.read(&text, sizeof(text));
  }
  int sensorVoltage = analogRead(A0);
  float nedVoltage = sensorVoltage * (4.2 / 1023.0);
  NedData.nedVoltage = nedVoltage;
  NedData.connectCount = NedData.connectCount + 1;
  radio.stopListening();
  bool ok = radio.write( &NedData, sizeof(NedData) );
  radio.startListening();


  Serial.print("fadeValue = ");
  Serial.println(fadeValue);
  Serial.print("NedData.connectCount = ");
  Serial.println(NedData.connectCount);
  Serial.print("NedData.nedVoltage = ");
  Serial.println(NedData.nedVoltage);
  Serial.print("SendData.X = ");
  Serial.println(SendData.X);
  Serial.print("SendData.Y = ");
  Serial.println(SendData.Y);
  Serial.print("SendData.R = ");
  Serial.println(SendData.R);
  Serial.print("SendData.G = ");
  Serial.println(SendData.G);
  Serial.print("SendData.B = ");
  Serial.println(SendData.B);
  Serial.print("SendData.Br = ");
  Serial.println(SendData.Br);
}
void doTheFade(unsigned long thisMillis) {
  // is it time to update yet?
  // if not, nothing happens
  if (thisMillis - previousFadeMillis >= fadeInterval) {
    // yup, it's time!
    if (fadeDirection == UP) {
      fadeValue = fadeValue + fadeIncrement;
      if (fadeValue >= maxPWM) {
        // At max, limit and change direction
        fadeValue = maxPWM;
        fadeDirection = DOWN;
      }
    } else {
      //if we aren't going up, we're going down
      fadeValue = fadeValue - fadeIncrement;
      if (fadeValue <= minPWM) {
        // At min, limit and change direction
        fadeValue = minPWM;
        fadeDirection = UP;
      }
    }
    // Only need to update when it changes
    strip.setPixelColor(4, 0, fadeValue, 0);
    strip.setPixelColor(5, 0, fadeValue, 0);
    strip.show();
    previousFadeMillis = thisMillis;
  }
}```
````

Comment: You are trying to do 1000000 FPS (update LEDs every μs). You are also sending your update via radio and outputing to serial on every `loop()` call.

Comment: I am using a millis timer for the led fade, so it does not change every cycle

Comment: `currentMillis = micros();` you are using micros.

Comment: Oh that was just a test to see if I made the timer faster if it would fix the issue it does not. Forgot I put this version in the code. I can fix that.